# p-divisible groups over a p-adic field

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, elliptic-curves

p-div gps over a finite field (e.g., $\mathbb F_p$) are classified by Dieudonne modules.

There are also results for p-div gps over integers of local fields (e.g., over $\mathbb Z_p$).

However, are there results for p-div gps over local fields (e.g.,$\mathbb Q_p$)? I couldn't find any references.. Or more generally, p-div gps over other fields?

Comment: Over a field of characteristic zero all formal groups are isomorphic. It is an elementary exercise to show the existence of a logarithm, i.e an isomorphism with the additive formal group. This is found, for example, in Silverman's Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves.

Comment: A $p$-divisible group over a field of characteristic $\ne p$ is exactly equivalent to the data of a continuous representation of the absolute Galois group on a finite free $\mathbf{Z}_p$-module.  In that generality these are total beasts, and there's not much one can say that is interesting.  Over $p$-adic fields and number fields one can say much more by bringing in techniques of $p$-adic Hodge theory, but that is a very long story.

Comment: @nfdc23 "but that is a very long story": Can you point some references? or names of mathematicians? thanks!

Comment: The range of topics around Galois representations and the Langlands program that have been influenced by $p$-adic Hodge theory is staggeringly vast (involving also Sato-Tate, Fermat's Last Theorem, etc.).  Just Google "$p$-adic Hodge theory" or "Fontaine-Mazur Conjecture", for example.  But this is getting way too far from what seems to have been the intent of your question, and $p$-divisible groups over fields not of char. $p$ (without reference to integral structure) are just $p$-adic Galois representations by another name; it is not a "good" way to view the latter.

Comment: @nfdc23 I see...so p-div gp over Q_p are really just Z_p representation of Gal(Q_P), right?

Comment: To be precise, if $k$ is a field with ${\rm{char}}(k)\ne p$ and absolute Galois group $\Gamma$ then the categories of continuous representations of $\Gamma$ on finitely generated free $\mathbf{Z}_p$-modules $L$ and (necessarily etale!) $p$-divisible groups $G$ over $k$ are equivalent: to any $G$ we associate the lattice representation $T_p(G)$ given by the inverse limit of $G[p^n](k_s)$'s, and given $L$ we assemble the finite etale $k$-groups $G_n$ associated to each $L/(p^n)=(1/p^n)L/L$ into a $p$-divisible group over $k$.